# magnify an area on an image when mouse hovers in bigcartel

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

I am in NO SHAPE or form a coder, but have made some tweaks to my BigCartel site that is expected to come out in the next few weeks. I have a clothing line, and I wanted enable consumers who have selected a product, to be able to hover over the image of the product to view it magnified... (here is an example from Nike of what I mean: http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/breathe-womens-short-sleeve-running-top/pid-11319700/pgid-11619220 ) I wanted to know what code to use to make the image/product that a consumer has clicked on and is viewing larger/magnify when hovering over a certain area... I saw some codes uploaded, but SINCE I am not a professional coder, I was wondering WHERE to insert it in the custom coding . I have a CSS option, and HTML and I don't know if I should go to "Products" or the over all coding...(Sorry for the rookie question)...

I also want to know (If I can slide this question in there as well) How to speed up the speed of the slide show on my BigCartel site, and possibly even change it to a dissolve option... And, again, where would I insert that code..

I've made some minor changes on my own, but again, I am NO CODER and there are a few additional tweaks, I would love to make to not make my site so "cookie cutter" The good folks at BigCartel, sent me this link to search and ask questions on.  Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you, we'll need you to be much more specific. What elements are you trying to enlarge on hover? What is the code for them? Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code you have so far in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It may be helpful to link to the site itself. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this this always works for me https://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/yyaraz

**JS**

```
$('.tile')
    // tile mouse actions
    .on('mouseover', function(){
      $(this).children('.photo').css({'transform': 'scale('+ $(this).attr('data-scale') +')'});
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(){
      $(this).children('.photo').css({'transform': 'scale(1)'});
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(e){
      $(this).children('.photo').css({'transform-origin': ((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 +'%'});
    })
    // tiles set up
    .each(function(){
      $(this)
        // add a photo container
        .append('<div class="photo"></div>')
        // some text just to show zoom level on current item in this example
        .append('<div class="txt"><div class="x">'+ $(this).attr('data-scale') +'x</div>ZOOM ON<br>HOVER</div>')
        // set up a background image for each tile based on data-image attribute
        .children('.photo').css({'background-image': 'url('+ $(this).attr('data-image') +')'});
    })
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="tiles">
    <div class="tile" data-scale="1.1" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/0yS4A9e.jpg"></div>
    <div class="tile" data-scale="1.6" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/hzQ2IGW.jpg"></div>
    <div class="tile" data-scale="2.4" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/bNeWGWB.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:700);

  body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .tiles {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .tile {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .photo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: transform .5s ease-out;
  }

  .txt {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
  }

  .x {
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you SO much @TheBeast95123 ... By any chance, do you know where I paste this in at? Can it go anywhere in the coding?

Comment: can you except my answer please? @PrettySoul

Comment: @PrettySoul paste the css with your other css put the js in the footer and put the html where ever you want it